# Convert part of an Object from numeric keys to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following Object

```
let demo = {a:'b', c:{0:{id:'one'},1:{id:'two'}}, d:{0:{country: {0:{name:'mx'},1:{name:'usa'}} }} };
```

The keys, example (0, 1), are integrated into an array, as shown below:

```
let result = {a:'b', c:[{id:'one'},{id:'two'}], d:[{country:[{name:'mx'},{name:'usa'}] }] };
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the object to new object, and convert each object that has the key `0` to an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const demo = {a:'b', c:{0:{id:'one'},1:{id:'two'}}, d:{0:{country: {0:{name:'mx'},1:{name:'usa'}} }} };

const arrayfy = (o) => Object.entries(o)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if(typeof v === 'object') {
      const t = arrayfy(v);
      r[k] = '0' in v ? Object.values(t) : arrayfy(t);
    } else {
      r[k] = v;
    }
  
    return r;
  }, {});
  
const result = arrayfy(demo);

console.log(result);
```